# Is the below code captures the exceptions from original, continuation and child tasks in TPL?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am using TPL and async/await to build async API on top of webclient for my applications. And few of the places (generally where I need to run bunch of async tasks and wait for all of them in the end), am following code snippet. I just want to make sure I get it correct as even though writing async code is relatively easy with TPL and async/await **debugging/trouble shooting is still challenging** (both interactive debugging and troubleshooting issues at customer site) - so want to get it right.

**My Goal:** Able to capture the exception generated from the original task, continuation tasks as well as child tasks, so that I can handle it (if I need to). I don't want any exception to be fir and forgotten.

**Basic principals I used:** 1. .net framework ensures the exception will be attached to task
2. Try/catch block can be applied to async/await to give illusion/readability of sync code (references: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2014-the-Netherlands/Async-programming-deep-dive, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/11/19/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-seven-exceptions.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614.aspx etc.)

**Question**: I would like to get ratification that the desired goal (that I can capture exception from original, continuation and child tasks) has been achieved, and is there any improvements I can do to the sample:

For example, will there be a case where one of the composed tasks (for ex, unwrapped proxy task) won't be activated at all (waitforactivation state), so that waitall may simply wait for the task to start? My understanding is that these cases should never happens as the continuation task always executes, and returns a task which has been tracked by proxy using wnwrap. As long as I follow similar pattern in all layers and apis, the pattern should capture all the aggregated exceptions in the chained tasks.

**Note:** essentially am looking for suggestions like avoiding dummy task am creating in continuation task if original task status is not ran to completion, or using attach to parent so that I can wait only on parent etc. to see all possibilities so that I can pick the best option as this pattern am heavily relying in my app for error handling.

```
static void SyncAPIMethod(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                List<Task> composedTasks = new List<Task>();
                //the underlying async method follow the same pattern
                //either they chain the async tasks or, uses async/await 
                //wherever possible as its easy to read and write the code
                var task = FooAsync();
                composedTasks.Add(task);
                var taskContinuation = task.ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                        //Intentionally not using TaskContinuationOptions, so that the 
                        //continuation task always runs - so that i can capture exception
                        //in case something is wrong in the continuation
                        List<Task> childTasks = new List<Task>();
                        if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                        {

                            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                            {
                                var childTask = FooAsync();
                                childTasks.Add(childTask);
                            }

                        }
                        //in case of faulted, it just returns dummy task whose status is set to 
                        //'RanToCompletion'
                        Task wa = Task.WhenAll(childTasks);
                        return wa;
                    });
                composedTasks.Add(taskContinuation);
                //the unwrapped task should capture the 'aggregated' exception from childtasks
                var unwrappedProxyTask = taskContinuation.Unwrap();
                composedTasks.Add(unwrappedProxyTask);
                //waiting on all tasks, so the exception will be thrown if any of the tasks fail
                Task.WaitAll(composedTasks.ToArray());
            }
            catch (AggregateException ag)
            {
                foreach(Exception ex in ag.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    //handle it
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review question, which should be on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Eugene, i kind of know the pattern i used most likely works - but the intention is to making sure and make it better. For ex, in continuation block am always creating dummy task with task when all to ensure i can capture unwrapped task error. same thing for nested tasks by using unwrap. Just want to make sure am using correct extensions (for ex, is it better to attach continuation and child tasks to original task and simply wait on it?)

Comment: IMO, this code could could have been much more simpler and elegant with `async/await`. I don't understand the reason why you stick with `ContinueWith` and `Unwrap`, and why you add both the inner and the outer (unwrapped) task to `composedTasks`.

Comment: @Noseratio, wherever I am using/able to use async/await in async apis/method am simply wrapping them in try/catch (and yes, its much better and elegant). But note that this is not a 'async' method and it is 'sync' call - there are some apis which still require syn api support. So, for this I had to use continue/unwrap to compose all tasks and wait for them in the end.

Comment: @Dreamer, anything returning a `Task` can be treated as async. I'm posting [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24550400/1768303) as an answer as it wouldn't fit the comment format.

Comment: @Noseration, now I got it:). I have one question though, please see below. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments:

> IMO, this code could could have been much more simpler and elegant
>   with async/await. I don't understand the reason why you stick with
>   ContinueWith and Unwrap, and why you add both the inner and the outer
>   (unwrapped) task to composedTasks.

What I meant is something like below. I think it does the same thing as you original code, but without unnecessary redundancy in form of `composedTasks`, `ContinueWith` and `Unwrap`. You almost never need those if you use `async/await`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<Task> doAsync = async () =>
    {
        await FooAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        List<Task> childTasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            var childTask = FooAsync();
            childTasks.Add(childTask);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(childTasks);
    };

    try
    {
        doAsync().Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ag)
    {
        foreach (Exception ex in ag.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            //handle it
        }
    }
}

static async Task FooAsync()
{
    // simulate some CPU-bound work
    Thread.Sleep(1000); 
    // we could have avoided blocking like this:        
    // await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000)).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // introduce asynchrony
    // FooAsync returns an incomplete Task to the caller here
    await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

**Updated** to address the comment:

> there are some use cases where i continue after 'creating child tasks'
>   to invoke more 'independent' tasks.

Basically, there are three common scenarios for any asynchronous task workflow: sequential composition, parallel composition, or any combination of these two (mixed composition):

- sequential composition:

  ```
  await task1;
  await task2;
  await task3;
  ```
- parallel composition:

  ```
  await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);

  // or

  await Task.WhenAny(task1, task2, task3);
  ```
- mixed composition:

  ```
  var func4 = new Func<Task>(async () => { await task2; await task3; });
  await Task.WhenAll(task1, func4());
  ```

If any task of the above does a CPU-bound work, you can use `Task.Run` for that, e.g.:

```
    var task1 = Task.Run(() => CalcPi(numOfPiDigits));
```

Where `CalcPi` is a synchronous method doing the actual calculation.

Comment: +1 Ohh, cool - this is much better. I have one question though - with my version, the code guarantees that thread whichever is calling will do some CPU work and then wait. But with, async/await version in lamda, looks like the thread most likely waits immediately.

Comment: @Dreamer, as with your version, this totally depends on what's inside `FooAsync`. The thread which calls `doAsync` will be blocked until asynchrony is introduced somewhere inside `FooAsync`. I've updated the answer to illustrate that, note `Thread.Sleep(1000)` inside `FooAsync`, it's a placeholder for any CPU-bound work you may have there.

Comment: but with this 'doAsync' simply returns with the generated task at "await" statement. And it resumes iff the async task completes from the statement next to await, and start composing child tasks. But, whereas in my version in the question, once fooasync returns, I still compose and do more CPU bound work - whereas here, it block and does more CPU work only after the first await completes in doasync.

Comment: @Dreamer, what CPU work are you referring to? I don't think you're doing anything in *parallel* with `fooasync` in your code, as to `composedTasks`. That's because anything you do inside `ContinueWith` will be executed *after* `fooasync` has completed. Essentially, only 1 task out of the 3 added to `composedTasks` is "hot", unlike with `childTask`.

Comment: ohh, thats true from the example - but there are some use cases where i continue after 'creating child tasks' to invoke more 'independent' tasks. But, you are correct - i should update the question. Let me think about it, and will update tomorrow (time to sleep). If i can able to use ur pattern in all the other cases, i will go ahead and accept it as answer tomorrow. thank you.

Comment: @Dreamer, I've updated the answer to address your last comment.

Comment: cool. I have marked it as answer its one of the best alternatives. Just one minor comment though: by following approach (especially in mixed cases), probably one end up with lot of  generated code, which is probably not so intuitive in error cases (for ex, stack trace). Regards.

Comment: @Dreamer, IMO, it's more intuitive to use `async/await` as opposed to `ContinueWith/Unwrap`, because I can use use all normal C# language statements, like `using`, `try`, loops etc. The code remains readable and maintainable even for complex task compositions. You can't do so with `ContinueWith`, where the more complex the logic is, the more code looks like "callback pyramid of doom".

Comment: I understand that using async/await is readable and looks alike to synchronized code.I am using async/await extensively especially when i don't have compose "mixed" tasks as in your answer.  I am mainly referring to error cases, one may need to be careful as lot of code may be generated-For ex,if an exception is thrown once code after await resumes, the callstack refers to the line number in "move next" generated method. And it becomes more complex if async/await lambda methods are used, and even so if interactive debugging is not possible, or doesn't repro consistently (timing issues) etc.