# How to process tasks as they complete -but each task requires different method to process task's result

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

I'm using async/await to call few external APIs. All of them returns me a string value but in different format and requires their own processing. 
And I want to process the returned value as a task completes. I don't want to wait until all are completed and hence I'm using Task.WhenAny(). How can I process tasks as they complete and still use the correct "Process" method for each task as they complete?

I make some changes after my first post and here is the latest i have:

```
public async Task<List<string>> Get()
{
    var task1 = Method1Async();
    var task2 = Method1Async();
    var tasks = new List<Task<string>> {task1, task2};
    var results = new List<string>();
    while (tasks.Count > 0)
    {
        var justCompletedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);//will not throw
        tasks.Remove(justCompletedTask);
        try
        {
           var result = await justCompletedTask;
           results.Add(result);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        { 
          //deal with it
        }
    }

    return results;
}

private async Task<string> Method1Async()
{
    //this may throw - something like forbidden or any other exception
    var task = _httpClient.GetStringAsync("api1's url here");
    var result = await Method1ResultProcessorAsync(task);
    return result;
}

private async Task<string> Method1ResultProcessorAsync(Task<string> task)
{
    //process task's result -if it successuflly completed and return that
    return await task; //for now
}

private async Task<string> Method2Async()
{
    //this may throw - something like forbidden or any other exception
    var task = _httpClient.GetStringAsync("api2's url here");
    var result = await Method2ResultProcessorAsync(task);
    return await task;
}

private async Task<string> Method2ResultProcessorAsync(Task<string> task)
{
    //This processing logic is entirely different from Method1ResultProcessor
    //process task's result -if it successfully completed and return that 
    return await task; //for now
}
```

I have two questions here:

1. Is this the right way to approach the problem?
2. How do i better handle exception here? This is very important so the failure of one should not fail the whole thing. As long as any of the methods succeed, it will be okay. But if all fails, I want to the Get method to throw.

Comment: Show the code you are using.

Comment: I updated it with code sample

Comment: Can you please tag with the language you are using. I never seen that before :-)

Comment: Its a C# 5.0 feature async/await. Tag added. Thanks for point that I3arnon & Klaus

Comment: @user3818435, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24550400/1768303) for some ideas on how to create complex compositions of tasks continuations.

Comment: Why not just create a new async method that awaits Method1Async and then awaits Method1ResultProcessorAsync method?  It doesn't sound like you need anything complex.

Comment: @Matt, its because I wanted to process tasks as they complete. If I await for first task and then for the second and if the second tasks completes first, I don't want to wait until the first task completes to process task2's result. I figured it myself and is now working fine. But I'm not sure still on the exception part yet.

Comment: Take a look on Task.ContinueWith http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @modosansreves, ContinueWith is for tasks that should be completed in particular order. My problem is to process as they complete instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your processor methods already accept `Task`, you can just call them and they will asynchronously wait for their corresponding results:

```
public Task<string[]> Get()
{
    var task1 = Method1ResultProcessorAsync(Method1Async());
    var task2 = Method2ResultProcessorAsync(Method2Async());

    return Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
```

Handling exceptions the way you describe will make this more complicated, but you can use something like:

```
public async Task<List<string>> Get()
{
    var task1 = Method1ResultProcessorAsync(Method1Async());
    var task2 = Method2ResultProcessorAsync(Method2Async());

    var tasks = new[] { task1, task2 };

    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    catch {}

    var results = tasks.Where(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                       .Select(t => t.Result)
                       .ToList();

    if (results.Any())
        return results;

    // or maybe another exception,
    // since await handles AggregateException in a weird way
    throw new AggregateException(tasks.Select(t => t.Exception));
}
```

Comment: I think i like this even better-it will be more readable i think. But i will pass in the result processor as an argument to the external api caller method or use continuewith chaining for just that as @modosansreves mentioned below instead. It needs some cleanup but i think this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is an alternative way of describing `Method1Async()` and `Method2Async()`. This is the demonstration of `ContinueWith`. Answering the question you ask in title – you do can use a different method for each task, that method will be called *after* the task completes.

   ```
   var task1 = _httpClient.GetStringAsync("api1's url here").ContinueWith(t => Method1ResultProcessorAsync(t));
   var task2 = _httpClient.GetStringAsync("api2's url here").ContinueWith(t => Method2ResultProcessorAsync(t));
   ```
2. You handle the exceptions correctly. Answering "But if all fails, I want to the Get method to throw.": just check whether `results.Count == 0` before the `return`, and `throw` if it 0.

Comment: thanks for your post. But how is this different than what i have? you have now two tasks (task1 and task2), when are you going to check if all tasks(in this case 2 tasks) failed? Could you please post your solution.